# what is difference between passe compose and imparfait?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

when we use passe compose and imparfait we intend a given time in past.
 But what is the distinction between them exactly?in other word, what is difference between passe compose and imparfait?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/passe-compose-versus-imparfait) site, the first result on Google for "passe compose vs imparfait"?

Comment: Quelle est la règle quand il y a doublon mais que le demandeur ne maîtrise pas suffisamment la langue pour s'approprier un contenu en français ?

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Ce serait une bonne question pour le French Language Meta

Comment: @comet: Volunteers can provide translations ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Le passé composé** is the past tense - it describes a brief action in the past.

But **l'imparfait** refers to past continuous - it actually describes a long action in the past, for example:

> "Je prenais une douche, soudain le téléphone a sonné"

Which means,

> "I was taking a shower; suddenly the phone rang"